# Typescript implementing a generic function that accept multiple type of inputs

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

For abstraction purposes I need to implement a function that accept different types of inputs.

```js
type ContentA = string

type ContentB = number

type InputA = {
 name: 'method_a'
 content: ContentA
}

type InputB = {
 name: 'method_b'
 content: ContentB
}

type Input = InputA | InputB
```

Each input is needed for a different method:

```js
const my_methods = {
 method_a: (content:ContentA) => {
  // ...
 },
 method_b: (content:ContentB) => {
  // ...
 }
}
```

Now I need to implement a generic function that accept all of the inputs, this is because the input types can be a lot, now there are only 2, but in my real application they are around 16.

I would like to have an implementation like this one, however it lead me to a compilation error:

```js
function foo(input:Input){
 return my_methods[input.name](input.content);
                             // ^
                             // | Argument of type 'string | number' is not  
                             // | assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
                             // | Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

Is there a way for Typescript to infer that since I am using `input.name` then the argument of the method is correct - since they will always match `input.name` and `input.content`?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BJBBKBeKBnYAnASwQHMAoU0SWRZJAIUygQFcBbAIwj3MugEkEYZsHRYA3qSYBDVhABcUAOSzgACzgATAPpTFkgMY0UwBfCTHUpAL49w-QcIbjJCGfKUr129nqiHzSKZG9Na2VAJCwIwRwugAPlAxwHTk-rhQrCBanprYjBIZEGqaOgoAFP60JmZVqACUmAB8UAVQAPRtUAB0PZJWADSSOd7llcZyNcZ0DRjNrR3dvVA2NqQAZswI+sAEiFBrcHBlRJFySXUFeEXMeAgZWcPYANonwl2usgC6xw7AXWNIOoAbmsQA)

Comment: Have you considered making `InputA` and `InputB` into classes, so you can simply add an overridable method onto them? I appreciate that this is not always possible, e.g. if they are parsed from JSON.

Comment: This can definitely be done; see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for the feature request (I called it "correlated unions") and [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) for the fix.  If I follow those directions with your code I get [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQ3bnm).   If that meets your needs I would be happy to write up an answer explaining it. If not, what am I missing?  (In either case, please mention @jcalz in your comment to notify me)

Comment: Ah, I would write up the answer but it looks like @ij7's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74153481/2887218) uses essentially the same technique.  Hopefully they will add in links to the GitHub issues above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting challenge, but I've found a nice enough solution that seems to work.

My idea is to take your initial union type `Input` and turn everything into generics instead, because narrowing discriminated unions (based on your `name`) really only works with literals.

First, let's create a type that has all possible `name` values:

```
type Names = Input["name"];
```

Next, create a "lookup" generic type that, given the `name` as the type argument, gives you the `content` type. For example, `ContentByName<"method_a">` is `ContentA`.

```
type ContentByName<TName extends Names> = {
  [i in Input as i["name"]]: i["content"];
}[TName];
```

With that, we create a specific type for your `my_methods` object. This seems to make it clear enough to the compiler that the names and types types really belong to each other:

```
type Methods = { [name in Names]: (content: ContentByName<name>) => void };

const my_methods: Methods = { // <-- added to your code here
  // ...
}
```

Finally your `foo` function also needs to be generic, for which we also need to create a generic version of the `Input` type.

```
type InputByName<TName extends Names> = {
  name: TName;
  content: ContentByName<TName>;
};

function foo<TName extends Names>(input: InputByName<TName>) {  // <-- added
  //...
}
```

Note that you can happily call this function with a plain ol' `Input` like you did before. This is completely valid:

```
function foo_old(input: Input) {
    return foo(input);
}
```

We didn't actually *change* anything about the types; we just helped the compiler reason about them.

Here's the [playground link with my changes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BJBBKBeKBnYAnASwQHMBuAKHNElkWSQCFMoEBXAWwCMI8KrxoASQRhWwdFgDe5KCwCG7CAC4oAIkXAAFnAAmAfTmqKsgMZ0UwFfCQXUFAL59qQkWKZSZ8xSvUQtuvU4jTzMbJCtzRgcnAShhUWBmeLF0AB8412AGGJoAOQUIbCTMgG1VBALVAF0c6Gt6LJB8xQAeABVm6AgAD3odIs7sAD5maVkSgigiDISoOSKCMorFaqqVRdVQhuqHEo6CmspnKABZP21+0agS5ehpwbWoAAotiwiwxs6W26GASkwRgA3OAEHRQRyUUK4KDsEB6DQXbAqM7+S4eWQIgJyFQvSKWWgfVD-DAjMayKAAegpUAAdHTPPYADSeTH6Tg417hAkNBjE0meWRU2n02RM8gQ-g0ZKfArtTpQHp9AYFYajTy3FT7RTGKCc-H1CwMJqyrUQIbRSgAM1YCBMwAIiCglrgcDlBQVvRQl0GQyeRASKmlRq+pr+UDJeD8rDwCBhcNZ2AmmRptyqfuTet+DitNrtDtjzrgejgABsdOmAzMxP8ybJI8BowWXRXqw4gA).

Comment: This is essentially the right answer, although you might want to link to the canonical documentation for it: [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) which reported the initial problem with correlated unions, and [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) which implemented some changes to accommodate using generics.

Comment: Thank you @ij7. Everything is clear. Just one thing. What exactly is happening when you define `ContentByName`? Why using `i in Input as i["name"]` instead of simple `i in Input`. Also why using at the end `{}[TName]`?

Comment: @47ndr In the first step, it's creating a type that represents a mapping from name to content type, i.e. `{ method_a: ContentA, ... }`. The `as i["name"]`is there because a property always has to be string, number, or symbol. In the second step, via `{}[TName]` we grab the entry from the type that corresponds to the type argument that we're looking for. You can think of the whole thing as the TS type version of `.map(...).find(...)`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for those links! I hadn't seen those yet. I wish the typescript team would migrate some of the great content they have in their PR discussions into the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware that the code in the playground is quite different from the one in the question.

The issue with this code is that you're not effectively narrowing the type / one way to do it effectively would be by using a switch statement:

```js
function foo(input: Input) {
    switch(input.name) {
        case 'method_a': {
            // input.content is guaranteed to be of type string
            console.log(input.content)
            break;
        }
        case 'method_b': {
            // input.content is guaranteed to be of type number
            console.log(input.content)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the playground link wasn't updated like the question. However, for your answer, I would like to avoid a `switch` since there might be a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions I can propose one of them:

Working [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BJBBKBeKBnYAnASwQHMAoU0SWRZJAIUygQFcBbAIwj3MugDkAhq2hYA5MOAALOABMA%20gNFQAPlHEQpsue1EBuHuGgBJBGGbB0WAN6kmQiAC4og4bYDGNFMCfwkX1KQAvgZUJmbADNa2CPZOLhDunkg%20SRFBIcam5oxh5uiquWmkHgi4UATYAPIAZgAqhoWWUAAUROEOhQCUTm3ZFVCNmAB8UDZQ41B4Gsx4COVZwAB0McKYGGIS0vKK%20sHFiGUVNfWQhZEtvd5dPQvl2AMLkSNjE1PAM3OXy-ZrGxpb2j06X2pWAUFYIDkm1k9yi4P%20WgETmaJVo3l8aNQnWGo1sUAA9PioIsSbZAgAaWzQ%20TsZGorwODFeOjYjDPPGE4mkqDBPbVZgINzAAiIKDVOBwVoLDoLTovcYEaoXKp1BoLVBS8KdbHyibjN4fcGQ6nYRbUhSa8yLelITr6PWBKAQAA22GgiuVxzV4ToluA2txer1BtmRqhCJkpvN7D91tSdrx40dLrdgaD4ykeDgAHcmBBcwBRPBZvDNAAG4rgzjgYOwzDAYDgeGQMnm4TLCYdQSAA)

```js
const isOfTypeInputA = (input:Input): input is InputA => {
    return input.name === 'method_a';
}

const isOfTypeInputB = (input:Input): input is InputB => {
    return input.name === 'method_b';
}

function foo(input:Input){
    if (isOfTypeInputA(input)) {
        return my_methods.method_a(input.content);
    } else if (isOfTypeInputB(input)) {
        return my_methods.method_b(input.content);
    } else {
        throw new Error(`foo Not supported input`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done, because what would the type of `my_methods[input.name]` be? It cannot be determined at compile time more strictly than `(ContentA) => void | (ContentB) => void`.

So you need a cast:

```
function foo(input:Input){
 return my_methods[input.name](input.content as any);
 //                                          ^^^^^^
}
```

Other answers propose solutions without a cast, which rely on control flow to do type narrowing. Those approaches are also valid, of course, and which is better depends on the situation and on preference.

One improvement you can make if you stick with your current approach, though, is to type `my_methods` more strictly, so that the compiler can check that the keys and argument types actually match the possible `Input` types:

```
type InputMethods = {
    [I in Input as I['name']]: (content: I['content']) => void
}

const my_methods: InputMethods = {
    method_a: (content: ContentA) => {
        // ...
    },
    method_b: (content: ContentB) => {
        // ...
    }
    
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BJBBKBeKBnYAnASwQHMAoU0SWRZJAIUygQFcBbAIwj3MugEkEYZsHRYA3qSYBDVhABcUAOSzgACzgATAPpTFkgMY0UwBfCTHUpAL49w-QcIbjJCGfKUr129nqiHzSKZG9Na2VAJCwIwRwugAPlAxwHRh9pEAshBqmtiMElAFUADafFBEiQ5RUrl8RYqusooAuk0KABT+tCaJdZ3GzQCUmAB8UABucAQaoaT+uFCsIFqeOQpJmdkauc6FCxCqwJo67X2B1AEiQxijYlAA9HdQAKJ4eHB4AIRQACrgcAA0e02OgWBGw2CIZF2uweUAAdAjJIUrP8kQUVt4TsFuuw4HAADYQKQIK43e6PF5vT5QADqbxIUCkeGIbGMUF4cLR0NhCM5uxRMwAZswEPpgAREFBBXi2kRInIkgN8ngssw8AgFksMdginLhHCGhAmrLKnDTsABgBuaxAA)

Comment: I tried your improvement but without any success. I don't know how to use the your index signature. Maybe you mean something like this [Playground link](https://shorturl.at/psHWZ) ? But it still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Playground link is broken, links to an entirely different website. Added a playground link to the answer.

Comment: Thank, but it seems it still doesn't compile in your playground. Sorry about my link. This is what I meant [Playground](tinyurl.com/mrjf8wc8)

Comment: Like I said, I think you need the cast. This isn't shown in my playground. The other error is deliberate, to show that the compiler can now check the method map for completeness and correctness.

Comment: I think the user [jcalz] got the solution. You can check it in the comment of the question.