# Why TS reporting error here: generic function that accept multiple type of inputs

Tags: typescript

This question was inspired by SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136673/typescript-implementing-a-generic-function-that-accept-multiple-type-of-inputs). Here is the code where error happens:

```
type ContentA = string

type ContentB = number

type InputA = {
 name: 'method_a'
 content: ContentA
}

type InputB = {
 name: 'method_b'
 content: ContentB
}

type Input = InputA | InputB

const my_methods = {
 method_a: (content:ContentA) => {
  // ...
 },
 method_b: (content:ContentB) => {
  // ...
 }
}

function foo(input:Input){
 return my_methods[input.name](input.content); // error Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.}
```

However, my question is not how to fix the error as the original question asked. My question is why is TS complaining?
Isn't the code typesafe?

For example `input` can either be `inputA` or `inputB` type. Say it is `inputA`, then `input.name` will be `method_a`, and `my_methods.method_a` expects argument of same type as `input.content` isn't it, so why error?

Comment: you should not just post the same question again.

Comment: The compiler is simply not advanced enough to do that. It sees `my_methods[input.name]` as `(_:ContentA) => {} | (_:ContentB) => {}` and `input.content` as `ContentA | ContentB`, but can't correlate the two unions.

Comment: @Blackhole Hm yeah now that's more the kind of answer I was looking for